# Google API login

Tags: php, google-analytics

I try to fetch data from google analytics using the [google api class](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) in php.
I checked serval google groups and found out that the error comes most of the time when Curl is off and SSL is off too, but I checked in the phpinfo() and booth are running. Anyone an idea what it could be? On my local server it's running, but on the webserver it's not running.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: &quot;Error=BadAuthentication
Url=https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=analytics#Email=mail
Info=WebLoginRequired
&quot;' in /home/express/public_html/loggedIn/gapi.class.php:418
Stack trace:
#0 /home/express/public_html/loggedIn/gapi.class.php(62): gapi-&gt;authenticateUser('mail', 'pw')
#1 /home/express/public_html/loggedIn/request.php(10): gapi-&gt;__construct('mail', 'pw')
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b
>/home/express/public_html/loggedIn/gapi.class.php</b> on line <b>418</b><br />
```

[image]

Comment: You should try the official Client library instead. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So after browsing more groups, a friend found out that you need to approve your account before you start fetching data for the first time [at this url](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Comment: That was it, Thanks! I noticed some accounts require to do it, others don't.

Comment: Another thing I had to do was, _enable access to less secure apps_ through [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). It's only in cases where your 2-step verification process is not enabled. I think in such case you could try creating an application specific password and use that instead.

Comment: Saved my life, I Can Has Kittenz!